# combine keys in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I map results of my query to create an array of hashes grouped by `organisation_id` like so:

```
results.map do |i|
  {
    i['organisation_id'] => {
      name: capability.name,
      tags: capability.tag_list,
      organisation_id: i['organisation_id'],
      scores: {i['location_id'] => i['score']}
    }
  }
```

a `capability` is defined outside the map.

The result looks like:

`[{1=>{:name=>"cap1", :tags=>["tag A"], :scores=>{26=>4}}}, {1=>{:name=>"cap1", :tags=>["tag A"], :scores=>{12=>5}}}, {2 => {...}}...]`

For every `organisation_id` there is a separate entry in the array. I would like to merge these hashes and combine the `scores` key as so:

`[{1=>{:name=>"cap1", :tags=>["tag A"], :scores=>{26=>4, 12=>5}}}, {2=>{...}}... ]`

## EDIT

To create the `results` I use the following AR:

```
Valuation.joins(:membership)
         .where(capability: capability)
         .select("valuations.id, valuations.score, valuations.capability_id, valuations.membership_id, memberships.location_id, memberships.organisation_id")
         .map(&:serializable_hash)
```

A `Valuation` model:

```
class Valuation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :membership
  belongs_to :capability
end
```

A `Membership` model:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :valuations
end
```

`results` snippet:

`[{"id"=>1, "score"=>4, "capability_id"=>1, "membership_id"=>1, "location_id"=>26, "organisation_id"=>1}, {"id"=>16, "score"=>3, "capability_id"=>1, "membership_id"=>2, "location_id"=>36, "organisation_id"=>1}, {"id"=>31, "score"=>3, "capability_id"=>1, "membership_id"=>3, "location_id"=>26, "organisation_id"=>2}, {"id"=>46, "score"=>6, "capability_id"=>1, "membership_id"=>4, "location_id"=>16, "organisation_id"=>2}...`

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: Your question would be improved greatly by giving an example for `results`.

Comment: Cary, see latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume for each organization: the name, taglist and organization_id remains the same.

```
your_hash = results.reduce({}) do |h, i|
  org_id = i['organisation_id']
  h[org_id] ||= {
    name: capability.name, 
    tags: capability.taglist, 
    organisation_id: org_id,
    scores: {}
  }
  h[org_id][:scores][i['location_id']] = i['score']
  # If the location scores are not strictly exclusive, you can also just +=
  h
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works, but data is needed to test it.

```
results.each_with_object({}) do |i,h|
  h.update(i['organisation_id'] => {
    name: capability.name,
    tags: capability.tag_list,
    organisation_id: i['organisation_id'],
    scores: {i['location_id'] => i['score']}) { |_,o,n|
      o[:scores].update(n[:score]); o }
  }
end.values
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Please consult the doc for the contents of each of the block variables `_`, `o` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, that `result` is your final array of hashes:

```
result.each_with_object({}) do |e, obj|
  k, v = e.flatten
  if obj[k]
    obj[k][:scores] = obj[k][:scores].merge(v[:scores])
  else
    obj[k] = v
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to change the code, rather than add code to convert the incorrect return value of the existing code.